# Codeigniter session to node js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, codeigniter, session

Im trying to implement realtime notifications and requests. Im using codeigniter and i want to use node js to provide a backend for a websocket to connect to.

I was thinking of storing codeigniter sessions in mysql, send this session to the user when it enters for the first time, then the socket can connect to node js suscribing using the session id.

When another user makes an action, node js looks by userid the active sessions that has to be notify and send them back to the client.

The flow would be something like this

User enters site -> codeigniter looks for the session and pass it to the view -> javascript websocket suscribes to nodeJs identifing himself with that session

Another user makes something -> javascript tell node js he did something -> node js look for affected users -> node js compare affected users against active sessions -> node js send back the new information to the websocket using the active session id

My question is, what are the security issues if i make this? if there are any, how it would be the correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: why not implement socket in php?

Comment: @charlietfl i havent use websockets till now, i only used them in java. Php has a way of keeping a socket running? how can i make codeigniter talk to the socket?

Comment: ratchet is one library ... do web search for *"php socket"* or *"php websockets"*

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl i already saw ratchet already but i cannot figure out how identify the users suscribed. I mean, when user A generates an action, notify user B but do not notify user C